# How can I change the background color of the Android tab with a renderer, while using a custom renderer to add some padding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my application I set the bottom tab bar background color like this:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
       x:Class="M.Views.AppShell"
       NavBarIsVisible="True"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Memorise"
       BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource ShellBackgroundColor}"
       TabBarBackgroundColor="{DynamicResource TabBarBackgroundColor}" 
       TabBarDisabledColor="{DynamicResource TabBarDisabledColor}" 
       TabBarForegroundColor="{DynamicResource TabBarForegroundColor}" 
       TabBarTitleColor="{DynamicResource TabBarTitleColor}" 
       TabBarUnselectedColor="{DynamicResource TabBarUnselectedColor}"
```

I create a custom renderer to add some side padding to the tabs on Android:

```
public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public CustomShellRenderer(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
    {
        return new MarginedTabBarAppearance();
    }
}

public class MarginedTabBarAppearance : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        if (App.devWidth == SIZE.L)
            bottomView.SetPadding(400, 0, 400, 0);
    }

    public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
    {
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this also has a side effect in that it sets the background color of the tab to white.

Does anyone have any knowledge of how I use this renderer and also change the background color to be the same as the DynamicResource ShellBackgroundColor?

**Code with renderers commented out:**

```
public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public CustomShellRenderer(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    //protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
    //{
    //    return new MarginedTabBarAppearance();
    //}
}

public class MarginedTabBarAppearance : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        //if (App.devWidth == SIZE.L)
        //    bottomView.SetPadding(400, 0, 400, 0);
        //if (Application.Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"] is Xamarin.Forms.Color color1)
        //{
        //    bottomView.SetBackgroundColor(color1.ToAndroid());
        //}
    }

    public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
    {
    }
}
```

**Tab bars with renderers commented out:**

[image]

** Code with renderers not commented out:**

```
public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public CustomShellRenderer(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
    {
        return new MarginedTabBarAppearance();
    }
}

public class MarginedTabBarAppearance : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        if (App.devWidth == SIZE.L)
            bottomView.SetPadding(400, 0, 400, 0);
        if (Application.Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"] is Xamarin.Forms.Color color1)
        {
            bottomView.SetBackgroundColor(color1.ToAndroid());
        }
    }

    public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
    {
    }
}
```

**Tab bars with renderers not commented out:**

[image]

**Updated code suggested by Mihail:**

```
public class MarginedTabBarAppearance :    ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{

public MarginedTabBarAppearance(IShellContext shellContext, ShellItem shellItem)
    : base(shellContext, shellItem)
{
}

public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
{
    base.SetAppearance(bottomView, appearance);

    bottomView.SetPadding(400, 0, 400, 0);

    if (Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey("TabBarBackgroundColor") && 
        Application.Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"] is Color tabColor)
    {
        bottomView.SetBackgroundColor(tabColor.ToAndroid());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `SetAppearance` method, you can set the background color like this:

```cs
bottomView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
```

However, the `SetBackgroundColor` requires a color of type `Android.Graphics.Color` and I see that you wish to take the color from a *DynamicResource*, which will return a `Xamarin.Forms.Color`. The good thing is that both color classes are easily convertable so we'll only need to take the current value of the *DynamicResource*:

```cs
if (Application.Current.Resources["CustomTabBackgroundColor"] is Xamarin.Forms.Color color)
{
    bottomView.SetBackgroundColor(color.ToAndroid());
}
```

Here, `CustomTabBackgroundColor` is the key for your color and `color.ToAndroid()` does the convertion between the 2 classes (from Xamarin's to Android's one).

**UPDATE**

Due to an update to the question, I'll add that the issue with the styles/colors resetting isn't in this case due to the backround change, but it's due to something else entirely. The way that a new view appearance is being set (`return new MarginedTabBarAppearance();`) resets all of the default styles. Since we are implementing everything from an *interface* and not deriving from the *base class*, we can't take anything from the already preset values. In order to fix that, we'll need to change the way the `MarginedTabBarAppearance` class is being implemented:

```cs
public class MarginedTabBarAppearance : ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    public MarginedTabBarAppearance(IShellContext shellContext, ShellItem shellItem)
        : base(shellContext, shellItem)
    {
    }

    public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        base.SetAppearance(bottomView, appearance);

        bottomView.SetPadding(400, 0, 400, 0);

        if (Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey("TabBarBackgroundColor") && 
            Application.Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"] is Color tabColor)
        {
            bottomView.SetBackgroundColor(tabColor.ToAndroid());
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you will have to change your `CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker` method like this:

```cs
protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
{
    return new MarginedTabBarAppearance(this, shellItem);
}
```

This way we'll take everything that we have already styled and we'll simply change what we'll need.

Comment: This works but now the selected and deselected colors no longer show. Do you have any idea of how to set these colors again?

Comment: Is it working when you set the color to some other Android color? If they turned out to be blue text on blue background, then you must dynamically set them too.

Comment: Yes it's blue text/icon for selected and gray icon/text for unselected. I added in the dynamic resources used to set the tab colors to the question.

Comment: What colors do you want them to be? And how are you setting the colors?

Comment: The colors of the tab icons are set from dynamic resources in the same way as the tab background.  Here's where all the colors are set: TabBarDisabledColor="{DynamicResource TabBarDisabledColor}" 
       TabBarForegroundColor="{DynamicResource TabBarForegroundColor}" 
       TabBarTitleColor="{DynamicResource TabBarTitleColor}" 
       TabBarUnselectedColor="{DynamicResource TabBarUnselectedColor}"

Comment: Can you update your question with what the colors are and maybe an image with how it's visible before/after? I doubt that setting the background color could break the colors, but still just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I have a question regarding the implementation call:  return new MarginedTabBarAppearance(); Can you give some advice on how I should set the parameters for this method call.  Thank you

Comment: apologies, I edited your answer by accident when trying to do a copy/paste of your suggested solution into my question. I think it's returned to the way it was now.

Comment: Works good now.  Thanks for all of your help.  I have a question for you.  My app currently uses Xamarin Shell as I thought it was easier to implement. However it seems to have made life a lot more difficult when doing advanced things and the app does not make use of any of the fancy side menus and things shell offers. Do you think a solution with a tabbed page / navigation pages and something such as tiny iOC for handling the routing would be more easy to customize or should I just stick with shell?

Comment: I haven't used Shell that extensibly to say for sure but, in my opinion, stick with it. It's a lot newer and will get better in time (with more functionalities than the traditional approach). Even if you don't use the "fancy" stuff, it's a lot more intuitive (navigation-wise). Xamarin plans to continue to use it and maybe, at some point, it will may the default navigation, deprecating other ways, who knows. When I start my next project, I plan to use shell all the way. The "traditional" approach also has its cons - sometimes you need to traverse the navigation tree and it's now the best thing.

Comment: Thanks Mihail, I've had a few problems with shell and navigation in the past.  If I get more problems I will open up questions like these and let you know. I will also be adding large bounties as I realize answers like yours do take a long time and I'm happy to reward in the form of a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Change the background color of TabBar with `SetBackgroundColor` method in `SetAppearance`.

Original screenshot:

[image]

Add the code in `SetAppearance` method:

```
bottomView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: A solution for this would be if I can get the current value of DynamicResource TabBarBackgroundColor and set the bottomView.SetBackgroundColor( xx ) to this color.  Do you know how to get the value of a DynamicResource inside of a custom renderer?

Comment: @Alan2 `bottomView` provide three ways to load the background. If you want to use the resource, you could try to use the `bottomView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.background);  `. I would upgrated the reply.

Comment: Hello, I added the results of my test to the question.  I am able to set the color.  However when I do that then the color of the tab icons no longer works.

Comment: I tried your method and it does set the background color.  However the tabs icons and text also lose their colors same as the example above and they default to Blue and Grey.

Comment: @Alan2 I cannot reproduce. Could you provide the dynamic resource of the color?