# How can I get a reference to the value of Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"] in an Android Custom renderer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"]


public class MarginedTabBarAppearance : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        if (App.devWidth == SIZE.L)
            bottomView.SetPadding(400, 0, 400, 0);
        bottomView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
    }

    public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
    {
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I canst the value of bottomView.SetBackgroundColor to the color represented by:

```
Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62755949/4090219), a dynamic resource value can be obtained like this everywhere, refering to `Application.Current`'s resources like this:

```cs
if (Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey("TabBarBackgroundColor") && 
    Application.Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"] is Color tabColor)
{
    bottomView.SetBackgroundColor(tabColor.ToAndroid());
}
```

You will need to convert the color from a Xamarin color to Android color. I have implemented this with the last line - `tabColor.ToAndroid()`.